# How to insert a cell with data into it into datagridview with single column?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a child form (form2) that is open and is having a datagridview with single column. I filled it with data using datatable.

Now, on a button click event of parent form (form1) i am opening another form (form3) that accepts some value. I want to insert that value in datagridview in child form (form2). That value is also updating database from where the data comes into datagridview.

IN FORM : 3

```
 Dim comStr As String = "Insert into Clinicinfo values (newid(), '" & clinicnameTxt.Text & "', '" & doctorsnameTxt.Text & "', '(" & doctordegreeTxt.Text & ")', '" & clinicaddresTxt1.Text & "', '" & clinicaddressTxt2.Text & "', '" & contactnoTxt.Text & "', '" & opeaningtimeDTP.Text & "', '" & closingtimeDTP.Text & "', 'Active')"
    Main.ClName = clinicnameTxt.Text
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand(comStr, conn)
    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to save data ?", "Saving Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) = vbYes Then
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfully.")
        'SelectClinic.clNameDGV.Rows.Add(New String() {clinicnameTxt.Text})////TRIED
        Dim adStr As String = "Select Distinct Clinic_Name from Clinicinfo Where Clinic_Status = 'Active'"

        Dim Adcomm As New SqlCommand(adStr, conn)
        Dim adrd As SqlDataReader
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        adrd = comm2.ExecuteReader
        dt.Load(adrd)
        Dim nf As New SelectClinic
        nf.clNameDGV.Columns.Clear()
        nf.clNameDGV.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        nf.clNameDGV.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        nf.clNameDGV.DataSource = dt

        rd.Close()
    End If
```

IN FORM 2 :

```
  comStr2 = "Select Distinct Clinic_Name from Clinicinfo Where Clinic_Status = 'Active'"
    End If
    Dim comm2 As New SqlCommand(comStr2, conn)
    Dim rd As SqlDataReader
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    rd = comm2.ExecuteReader
    dt.Load(rd)
    'clNameDGV.Columns.Clear()
    clNameDGV.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    clNameDGV.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    clNameDGV.DataSource = dt

    clNameDGV.Refresh()

    rd.Close()
```

IN FORM 1 :

```
   Private Sub CreateClinicAccountToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CreateClinicAccountToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim nf As New ClinicDetails
    nf.MdiParent = Me
    nf.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Kindly show us your code please. So we know what are you trying to pass where..

Comment: So.. You want some values in _Form3_ to be transferred in a _DataGridView_ in _Form2_ then you will save the values in _Form2_?

Comment: Yes. I want update datagridview with value got from form3. i.e. i  want value of clinicnameTxt.Text to be added into datagridview in form2